# Cypress with Checkout.com payments

Tags: cypress, checkout

I'm having some trouble getting Cypress to work with Checkout.com.

I can fill out my payment form, but when I submit the data, it looks like I get a response object back with a website to get a token:

`http://3ds2-sandbox.ckotech.co/....`

Then with that token, it seems that I need to send it to another URL in order for my payment to be accepted.

This all seems a big headache so I'm thinking that it's best that I simply mock the responses to test at least the functionality is working.

Has anyone done this previously? Or working with Checkout.com & Cypress?